# add variable on ejs include

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to load blog partials using `include` from ejs according to the `name` of blogs.

Data from data.json:

```
"blogs" : [{
    "title" : "Git Basics",
    "name" : "git_basics",
    "date" : "February 8, 2015",
    "category" : "git",
  },{
    "title" : "Javascript Basics",
    "name" : "javascript_basics",
    "date" : "December 31, 2014",
    "category" : "javascript"
  },{
    "title" : "Html5 Communication",
    "name" : "html5_communication",
    "date" : "November 25, 2014",
    "category" : "html5"
  }]
```

route:

```
/* GET blog page. */
router.get('/blog', function(req, res) {
  var blogswithDetail = [];
  for(var i=0; i<appdata.blogs.length && i<4; i++){
    blogswithDetail.push(appdata.blogs[i]);
  }

  res.render('blog', { 
    title: 'Blog',
    blogswithdetail: blogswithDetail
  });
});
```

page:

```
<% blogswithdetail.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <article id="<%= item.name %>">
        <h2><%= item.title %></h2>
        <p><%= item.date %></p>
        <%= item.detail %>
    </article>
    <% include partials/content/blog_(item.name).ejs %>
<% }); %>
```

`<% include partials/content/blog_(item.name).ejs %>` This line of code is incorrect. **My question is how can I insert `item.name` into `include`**, so I can include different partials according to the change of `item.name`

Comment: Could you please provide more details. It is not very clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @NarendraSoni Thanks. I have specified my question. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @NarendraSoni I added more details again. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood how ejs work.
ejs take the argument provided, and replace the tag with the argument:

node.js:

```
res.render('test.ejs', {a: 'hello', b: 'world', c: 42});
```

test.ejs:

```
<%= a %><%= b %><br>
The answer to life, universe and everything else is <%= c %>
```

Result:

```
helloworld<br>
The answer to life, universe and everything else is 42
```

You can pass object:

```
res.render('test.ejs', {a: {a: 'a', b: 'b'}});
```

But you can t use a property of the object, just the entire object.

In your case, you should do:

node:

```
var item = {name: 'name', title: 'title', date: 'date', details: 'details'};
res.render('test.ejs', item);
//Or
//res.render('test.ejs', {name: item.name, title: item.title...
```

ejs:

```
<% blogswithdetail.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <article id="<%= name %>">
        <h2><%= title %></h2>
        <p><%= date %></p>
        <%= detail %>
    </article>
    <% include partials/content/blog_(<%= name %>).ejs %>
<% }); %>
```

Or:

```
<% blogswithdetail.forEach(function(){ %>
    var item = JSON.parse(<%= item %>);
    <article id="item.name">
        <h2>item.title</h2>
        <p>item.date</p>
        item.detail
    </article>
    <% include partials/content/blog_(item.name).ejs %>
<% }); %>
```

node:

```
res.render('test.ejs', {item: JSON.stringify(item)});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. But actually I can use the properties of object. When I deleted this line of code  `<% include partials/content/blog_(item.name).ejs %>`, the page could be rendered correctly. So I think the grammar of this line of code is incorrect. The question is I don't know how to insert `item.name` into `include`

Comment: I added more details about the question. Can you spend a little more time help me solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the trick here. When we develop any web application, we should try to make it dynamic. Gone are the days when we used to have 100s of HTML and load them based on routes, that's basically called as static web.

What i understand from your question is that you are trying to load a particular EJS template based on param value. Just think of a situation, your project keeping getting bigger and bigger as the time progress  and so as your param values and for every specific param you are going to create a new EJS template which is not much different from the others. There will be 100s of files which will be difficult to manage.

So i suggest you to use templating the right way. Just include one EJS template and inside that make use of expressions to distinguish b/w your `item.name` and render the view as required. Of course you have to use it intelligently, if you think there are chances to simplify use should break templates to even smaller and re-use the existing ones.

example  :

```
<%if (item.name == 'xyz') { %>
// Do something 
<% } %>
```

Comment: I am just building a small website to manage my own tech blogs. Because the tech blogs have many codes and different structures which I don't know how to store them into database. So I put the content of each blogs into partials, which I think is a easier way to approach. I can not think a better way to manage them. If you have some good idea. Please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Since you are working on Node and EJS, i would suggest you to go for MEAN(Mongo, Express, Angular, Node). Use express as Rest Engine and Angular JS for all the front end routing and view logic. I am sure you would love this. For example looks [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-jwt-auth).

Comment: Thank you. That is what I am trying to learn. In that way, I should store my blog contents into MongoDB, right? But in the tech blogs, there are some codes between `<pre><code>` should be stored in their original form, how can I do that in database?